# Firebase Functions : SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I had an error in deploying Firebase functions after I changed my laptop and also transferred ownership of my Firebase account to another for a 3-month free Blaze plan. While deploying any functions, I am getting this error. All Firebase functions are successfully running locally.

## Error code

```
 <Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>
<StringToSign GET 1670330017 /uploads-abc.zip</StringToSign></Error>
```

## index.js

`

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
var handlebars = require("handlebars");
var fs = require("fs");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");


var serviceAccount = require("../service_account.json");
admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
   storageBucket: "gs://xyz.com",
   databaseURL: "https://xyz",

});


transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "username",
      pass: "password",
    },
  });

readHTMLFile = function (path, callback) {
    fs.readFile(path, { encoding: "utf-8" }, function (err, html) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err);
        throw err;
      } else {
        callback(null, html);
      }
    });
  };

exports.sendWelcomeMail = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // Grab the text parameter.
    const email = data.email;
    const name = data.name;
    readHTMLFile(`./welcome_page.html`, function (err, html) {
      var template = handlebars.compile(html);
      var replacements = {
        name: name,
      };
      var htmlToSend = template(replacements);
      var mailOptions = {
        from: "from-mail",
        to: email,
        subject: "Welcome to boom boom",
        html: htmlToSend,
      };
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
        if (erro) {
          console.log(erro.toString());
          return erro.toString();
        }
        console.log("Sended");
  
        return "Sended";
      });
    });
  });
```

`

I had tried different service account private keys which we can get from firebase project settings, with that I had tried deploying functions from different account ex. owners account, other account with service admin access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check that SHA keys (SHA-1 and SHA-256) in your Firebase project (Project Settings -> General -> Your Apps -> Select your android app -> SHA certificate fingerprints) are same as in Google Play Console (Setup -> App integrity -> App Signings -> App Signing Key Certificate).

Specially if you are using Google play signing to release your app.

Comment: Thanks it worked, it was one of the reason with this I had done many other changes too

Comment: The following is a list of changes I made in the previous week to the backend for function deployment.
• SHA1 and SHA256 keys added to the Firebase project
• downgraded the Firebase cli tool version from 11.0.0 to 10.0.0.
• All functions are written in the index.js file (to organise files, read Firebase documents).
• removed the service account key (Firebase was not able to detect the local path on deployment) as it was not required.
• Unless you are using the owner account, use the account that has the required permissions to deploy functions.

Answer (score 0):

try in your terminal :

1. login with your firebase account  **firebase login:ci** you will be redirected to your browser, you have to login
2. come back to the terminal (now you are logged in) and type **firebase projects:list** to list all the projects that you can access with your logged in firebase account
3. choose the project you want to deploy your function to : **firebase use** 
   NB: you are assumed to have npm and firebase-tools already installed in your terminal

Comment: I am already logged in with the owner account and have followed all these steps because without that I will not be able to use "firebase serve" to run functions locally, as all functions are running perfectly locally.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: same issue, any solution?